# Namespacing a collection of classes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, namespaces

I'm developing in node.js.  I have a bunch of related classes that I want to stick in a subdirectory, one class per file in the subdirectory, structured along these lines:

```
 lib/
   main.js
   melons/
     casaba.js
     canteloupe.js
     carnegie.js
```

And use them in my main file like this:

```
var Melons = require('./melons/');
var m1 = new Melons.Casaba();
var m2 = new Melons.Canteloupe();
var m3 = new Melons.Carnegie();
```

I *think* I need a melons/index.js file, but I'm not clear on what it would contain.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create `melons/index.js`, structured like this:

```
// file: melons/index.js
module.exports = {
  Casaba: require('./casaba'),
  Canteloupe: require('./canteloupe'),
  Carnegie: require('./carnegie'),
};
```

Make sure that each of the files in the sub-directory has an `module.exports` assignment, such as:

```
// file: melons/casaba.js
'use strict';

function Casaba() {}
Casaba.prototype.constructor = Casaba;

module.exports = Casaba;
```

I believe this is an idiomatically appropriate solution, but if there's a better way, please let me know...